# Append property of struct to array using reduce

Tags: swift

I have an array of Items

```
struct Item {
    var id: String
}
```

How can I append all the ids to an array using **reduce** function?

What I try:

```
self.items.reduce([String](), { $0.0.append($0.1.id)})
```

But compiler shows an error:

> Contextual closure type '(_, [Item]) -> _' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it with reduce, here is a snippet for Swift 3 and 4:

```
struct Item {
    var id: String
}

var items = [Item(id: "text1"), Item(id: "text2")]
let reduceResult = items.reduce([String](), { $0 + [$1.id] } )
reduceResult // ["text1", "text2"]
```

There were 2 issues:

1. Reduce is giving you 2 arguments, not single tuple with 2 values
2. You can't edit argument that is passed to you in the block, you have to return new object

But in this case the best solution is to use map:

```
let reduceResult = items.map { $0.id }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
items.reduce([String](), { res, item in
    var arr = res
    arr.append(item.id)
    return arr
})
```

Comment: Error: Value of type '[Item]' has no member 'id'

Comment: Sorry, updated... As @vadian said though, you probably really want to use `map`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably mean `map` rather than `reduce`

```
let ids = items.map{ $0.id }
```